# Making multi-layer mvt vector tile

Tags: sql, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to make multi-layer vector tile using SQL query. I could able to make Mvt tile, but that was only for single layer. I got binary file from that query.

How can I make multi-layer Mvt vector tile? I need the same binary file.